# How to View System Apps in 4.2.2

Tags: printing

How are the System Apps viewed in 4.2.2?
There is not a More, or Show System Apps that I can see,

I'm answering questions for a Samsung support person (Print spooler Version?) about Samsung Print Service Plugin problems.(it works on a 4.2.2 Tab & 6.0.1 Tab, not on a Galaxy S5).  Only Downloaded, SD Card, Running, and All apps are listed under 4.2.2 apps.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The system does not provide such option, apps are not filtered, all apps are listed in **All tab**. 
You can filter apps by type  using an app such as [**ES Explorer**.](http://www.estrongs.com/?lang=en)

Open the app, touch the android logo labelled APP, then touch the dropdown menu and select system apps.

[image: ES Explorer screenshot]
[image: ES Explorer screenshot]

<sub>Click image for larger version</sub>

Comment: I looked in the 'All' but there is not a Print Spooler listed, or Spooler.  I will see if ES Explorer lists it.

Comment: Maybe because you don't have it installed. Did you check in Settings > More Connection Settings > Printing ? I don't own an S5, but on my J5 the option is present

Comment: This Tab prints perfectly, maybe spooler is there somewhere.  I'm just looking for it to provide Samsung with the spooler version.  I'm working with a Sam Tab Lite 7" (Android 4.2.2 at the moment).  I found the spooler in the Sam Gal S5 easily.  I'll resume this project later today.

Comment: Okay. Do you have Samsung Printing Service Plugin app installed? Can you find it in the tablet?

Comment: Yes I can find the Samsung printer plugin (also the HP printer plugin).  I must say I have setup probably 100 or more Androids to print, Samsung Tablets, S5, and S7, but have not experienced this S5 failure.